# How do you set the selected image for a button in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I know how to change the image programatically when a button is pressed, but there must be a way to do this non programatically in Xcode, but despite searching high and low I simply cannot see anywhere in Xcode where the selected image can be specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try in your storyboard.  The second selection (STATE CONFIG) down in attributes inspector should show "default" for your button. Change the sate (Highlighted, selected, disabled) and then change the image in the image box 8 down or background image underneath.[image]

Comment: Hahaha, thanks :) first one I have known..was typing crazy to get it in there, beaten to the punch! ;)

Comment: Wonderful! I was thinking XCode is wired! Who knows these little things when we learn here and there!

Answer (score 0):

Open up the "Attributes Inspector" in your storyboard or XIB and the image name is an attribute you can set in your UIButton object.

[image: set your attribute here]

Also make certain to make the "Title" empty or a string will be drawn over your image.